# why is my python code not giving me the correct value?

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0by9.jpg) hi so like i have this notepad document full of words I want to use for my python code, but when I try to use random.choice() it only extracts certain letters instead of the whole word. what can I change to make it extract a whole word instead?

Comment: Because you never told it to. Are the words separated by commas, spaces, tabs, newlines, or some other sentinel? Python isn't going to guess at that sort of thing; you have to tell it

Comment: Please paste the text of your code and not an image.  Links and images of text should only be used when text is not sufficient to describe the problem.

Comment: Try using `.readlines()` except `.read()`

Answer (score 1):

You're reading your file into one big string. It's choosing a random letter from that string. If you split that string into a list of words, you can then choose a word randomly from that list.